# How do you keep a ManyToMany relationship up to date?

Tags: django

I have the following classes:

```
class Plugin(models.Model):
    pass 

class Instance(models.Model):
    plugins = models.ManyToManyField(Plugin, blank=True, null=True)
```

My goal is to write a cron job which gets a list of plugins from this instance to reflect the instance_plugin relationship. **This means that if a plugin is removed from the instance in real life then it must also be reflected here**.

```
for instance in Instance.objects.all():
    url = 'http://{}/wordpress_plugins'.format(instance.ip_address)
    ... 
    plugins = []
    for path, dic in response.json().items():
        plugin, created = Plugin.objects.update_or_create(
             ... 
        )
        plugins.add(plugin)

    instance.plugin_set = plugins
```

I am getting `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use plugins.set() instead.`

What is the best approach to what I am doing?

Comment: Did you try using `plugins.set()` as the error message indicates?

Comment: do you want to add plugin to the Instance Model?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can do what you want to do.
If you edit you codes with the fields that all your models have, 
I can provide you a better one.

```
for instance in Instance.objects.all():
    url = 'http://{}/wordpress_plugins'.format(instance.ip_address)
    ... 
    plugins = []
    for path, dic in response.json().items():
        plugin, created = Plugin.objects.update_or_create(
            ... 
        )
        plugins.add(plugin)

    # First Option
    # We add each plugin from the Plugins List
    [instance.plugins.add(item) for item in plugins]
    # We loop through the instance to see which plugin is not in the New List Plugin, we delete it
    for plug in instance.plugins.all():
        if plug not in plugins:
            plug.delete()


    # 2nd Option
    # We clear the intance ManyToMany Field
    instance.plugins.clear()
    # We add each plugin from the Plugins List
    [instance.plugins.add(item) for item in plugins]
    # We loop The all The Plugin, to see which plugin does not have a reverse relation to instance
    for plug in Plugin.objects.all():
        if not plug.instance_set.all():
            plug.delete()
```